# remove port number from list in notepad++

Tags: replace, notepad++

I have csv file that has the computer name in one column, and the same computer name with the port number on the second column.  I want to compare that the name in both column 1 and 2 are the same.  So I am trying to remove the `:#####` from the list.  How do I do this?

I can't post a picture as I am too new here, but it looks like  this:

```
ComputerName,ComputerName:18062

ComputerName2,ComputerName2:198099
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find `^((.*?),\2).*?$` and replace with `\1`. Use regular expression search mode, without `. matches newline`.

- `^` match start of line
- Outer `()` define group 1.
- `(.*?),` Match any character until `,` is found. Result is stored to group 2.
- `\2` Match same string again as in group 2.
- `.*?$` Match remaining characters until the end of line.
- Entire line is replaced with group 1.